# Display TimeSpan type Data in Angularjs Listing

Tags: angularjs, timespan, listings

Trying to show time in table but it shows me time in this format

```
{"Hours":16,"Minutes":8,"Seconds":45,"Milliseconds":0,"Ticks":581250000000,"Days":0,"TotalDays":0.6727430555555556,"TotalHours":16.145833333333332,"TotalMilliseconds":58125000,"TotalMinutes":968.75,"TotalSeconds":58125}
```

while i want it to be displayed in this format

```
"12:13:20"
```

In Html file i does listing like this

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in Festivals">
            <td>{{item.StartTime}}</td>
            <td>{{item.EndTime}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Angular controller code where i am initializing data

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('SeasonCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$http', 'seasonService', function ($scope, $http, seasonService) {

        $scope.Seasons = [];

        seasonService.GetAllSeasons = function () {
            seasonService.getSeasons().success(function (data) {
                $scope.Seasons = data.data;
            })
        }

        seasonService.GetAllSeasons();

    }
]);
```

C# Code i am sending data to angular controller

```
public JsonResult GetAllSeasons()
{
    var data = _seasonManager.AllSeasons();
    if (data != null)
    {
        var list = data.Select(r => new
        {
            r.StartTime,
            r.EndTime
        });

        return Json(new { data = list }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Can you show us the value of `item.StartTime`?

Comment: This value comes from DB when i check object through Break point
{StartTime = {14:44:45}, EndTime = {14:44:45}}
while in Browser it shows in this format

{"Hours":16,"Minutes":8,"Seconds":45,"Milliseconds":0,"Ticks":581250000000,"Days":0,"TotalDays":0.6727430555555556,"TotalHours":16.145833333333332,"TotalMilliseconds":58125000,"TotalMinutes":968.75,"TotalSeconds":58125}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just tried this and its solved my problem

In Html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in Festivals">
            <td ng-bind='timeFunction(item.StartTime)'></td>
<td ng-bind='timeFunction(item.EndTime)'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In Angular Controller

```
$scope.timeFunction = function (timeObj) {
      var min = timeObj.Minutes < 10 ? "0" + timeObj.Minutes : timeObj.Minutes;
      var sec = timeObj.Seconds < 10 ? "0" + timeObj.Seconds : timeObj.Seconds;
      var hour = timeObj.Hours < 10 ? "0" + timeObj.Hours : timeObj.Hours;
      return hour + ':' + min + ':' + sec;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses a filter and Moment.js.

In JS:

```
angular.module('app')
    .filter('showTimeSpan', function () {
        return function (timeObj, format) {
            return moment(timeObj, "HH:mm").format(format);
        };
    });
```

In HTML:

```
<p>{{activity.startTime | showTimeSpan:"hh:mm a"}}</p>
```